# Joomla and K2 - populate extra field with options from database

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

We're using Joomla! and K2. Is it possible to 'extend' a K2 extra field, to present an admin user with a drop-down populated with items from the database? The ID of the selected item would be stored against the extra field.

This seems like something that should be easy to achieve, but I haven't unearthed much information on extending K2.

Thanks,

Toby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it ever helps someone, we achieved this by overriding K2ModelItem (in templates\our_template\code\com_k2\models). We made the extra field a list type, and then added in our own code to pre-populate this in getItemExtraFields().

Toby